# React Fixed data table vertical scrolling not working in IE and MS edge

Tags: fixed-data-table

Vertical scrolling of the data table in this example https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-object-data.html
does not work in MS edge or IE. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is fixed in: http://schrodinger.github.io/fixed-data-table-2/

Fixed-Data-Table-2 is a continuation of facebook/fixed-data-table. The original repo is no longer maintained.